# Not able to get range of excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to extract certain data from a workbook to put into a different workbook. I've got the workbook to open using

```
Application.GetOpenFile
```

, and then assigning that to a workbook. Then I assign a sheet to the active worksheet from that workbook.

My problem is coming from trying to get the range of the worksheet. I'm using an array of strings (like

```
    columnLetter(0) = "A"
    columnLetter(1) = "B"
```

and so on to try to check through all of the columns for certain strings (which are listed in an if statement with a ton of "Or"s. The specific place of the strings varies from file to file, so my plan was to search the first row, then the second row, etc until it finds one of the strings. So, I'm using this:

```
    lastRow = brokerSheet.Range(columnLetter(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

to get the amount of rows in that column specifically. When I run the program, though, I get the error

```
    Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
```

on that line. I'm guessing that's because I'm trying to use

```
     columnLetter(i)
```

,which has A through R assigned to it, instead of "A" or something like that for the column name. However, I tried using 1, 2, 3, etc to represent first column, second column, third column...but that didn't work. The worksheet only has around 90 rows (though some will have upwards of 400 once I get this working). Is there another way to do this? I could write out "A" "B" "C" etc for all of them, but there has to be a better way to designate which column to check than that.

Comment: what extensions of your both files? Is there is one with `xls` extension (excel 2003)? Try to use `lastRow = brokerSheet.Range(columnLetter(i) & brokerSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Yeah, it's an `xls`. Tried that, getting the same problem. I figured it was with the `columnLetter(i)`.

Comment: try to use `lastRow = brokerSheet.Range("A" & brokerSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. Would it work?

Comment: `brokerSheet.Range(columnLetter(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` can be `brokerSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row` (i is 1-based) then you don't need that array.

Comment: Could it be how you define brokerSheet? Try something like (depends how you define your workbook) WB.brokersheet.range(...)
Or if your worksheet's name is actually brokersheet?

Comment: Using `lastRow = brokerSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp.Row)` gets rid of the error. I think that fixed it, but won't be sure until I figure out some other errors (I'm getting a similar error when it reaches `set compSheet = Sheets("Broker")`, which is the sheet the information from brokerSheet will be placed into).

Comment: If it is from the workbook where the code is running then `set compSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Broker")`

Comment: That's not the workbook "Broker" is located, though. It's located in the workbook I'm running the macro from. Give me a second to draw a diagram.

Comment: Yep, that fixed the error. Thanks! Just have to figure out how to get this to copy the values from the found column to the column in the Broker sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try creating a string object `strRange` and injecting this into `Range()`:

```
strRange = columnLetter(i) & CStr(Rows.Count)
lastRow = brokerSheet.Range(strRange).End(xlUp).Row
```

This should work

Comment: Yep! That worked, and made it a little cleaner than the other solutions. Thanks!